# Nuget CodeFirst EntityFramework Migration or Sync DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have been trying ASP.NET MVC 3 using Code-First approach with EntityFramework. There are couple of issues I am facing.

1. How do I sync the database if schema changes and/or I update my model. Right now i have to delete and re-create the database thus loose all my data. Is there a package available i can use to automatically update the schema. In one of the demos I saw Scott Hanselman using "EntityFramework.Migration" package. I guess that is not released use. Any alternatives?
2. MvcScaffolding recreates all View/Controllers. Is there a way to preserve CSS Styling in Views if the MVCScaffolding is executed and views are re-created.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Check this out - [EntityFramework.SchemaCompare](https://github.com/kriasoft/data)

Answer (score 2):

There are various tools to generate change scripts for databases. As far as entity framework itself, there is the soon to come EntityFramework.Migrations that will also handle this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx

I am not sure about your second question. I personally do not use the automatic generation of views, however, I believe you should be able to modify a T4 template to generate your views the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second question was more about preserving CSS styling in Views. Anytime Scaffold is run it overwrites and recreates the views thus any CSS class added to the views gets overwritten by default ASP.NET MVC theme.

Comment: +1 for the migrations. It's too easy to say "seed the database" but that's only good for development environments.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your data loss issue, look into using the database [initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) classes. You can seed data each time your model changes. I know this is not ideal, but it is all we have right now with EF 4.1. You can use something like [Red Gate's SQL tool-belt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=sqltoolbelt&gclid=CLi7vJnmgakCFUWA5Qod3DylUQ) to keep environments synced. As part of the package, you can sync data. You can always back-up the scripts created by SQLToolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

For Scaffolding issue, just change the scaffolding templates themselves so they contain the CSS classes. this way, whenever you re-scaffold, the CSS classes will be there.

[More about this here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/)